# Creating class instance based on class type?

Tags: java, java-7

I am using JAVA7. I have below class.

```
public class SomeClass<B extends Base, L extends Last>{
   Class<L> last;
   Class<B> base;

   public SomeClass(Class<L> last, Class<B> base){
       this.last=last;
       this.base=base;
   }
}
```

here i need to create a method which will accept class type and create its instance  and return. how can i do that?

`public returnclassinstance createInstance(Class class)`

I would call this method by passing either last/base. This method has to create the instance of the passed class type and return the same. Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Unless `Base` and `Last` has an `Is-A` relationship, no it's not possible.

Comment: Rohit, thanks for ur comment. Do i need to remove generics then?

Comment: I don't understand the need of generic class here. I would rather make that method generic.

Comment: Rohit, i could not understand.. Could you please provide your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create new instance based on java `Class` type, you should use something like this:

```
public <T> T createInstance(Class<T> clazz) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        return clazz.newInstance();
    }
```

Note that `T` should have public default constructor. If you want to use other that default construtors to create new instance of `Class`, then you should look into reflection (e.g. `clazz.getDeclaredConstructors()`).

EDIT: using constructor with arguments

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

public class Test {
    public Test(String arg) {
        System.err.println("I'm in consturctor with one String arg: " + arg);
    }

    public static <T extends Test> T createInstance(Class<T> clazz) throws InstantiationException,
            IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
        Constructor<T>[] constructors = (Constructor<T>[]) clazz.getDeclaredConstructors();
        Constructor<T> constructor = constructors[0];
        return constructor.newInstance("ARG");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        createInstance(Test.class);
    }
}
```

After running this code you should get on output:

```
I'm in consturctor with one String arg: ARG
```

But note how ugly this code is - using reflections in Java for such object creation is in my opinion the last option (if we don't have any other solutions).

Comment: Arek, thanks for ur answer. I need to pass values to constructor while instantiating. How can i do that?

Comment: @user755806 - I suggest you edit your question accordingly, so it contains all the information you need

Comment: @user755806 : as user503413 said - you should better specify your needs - my answer is only way how you can achieve object creation via Java reflection. There are a lot of possible error-generating places, so as I said in edited answer - using reflection for me is always last option.